# RPM doesnot take care of deleting the directories which are created as part of RPM relocation

Tags: directory, rpm, uninstallation, prefix, relocation

I have to relocate a rpm and hence i have added Prefix in my spec file.

rpm.spec:

Prefix: /etc

Prefix: /usr

Prefix: /var

when i do relocation :

rpm -ivh --relocate /etc=/akshatha/test/  --relocate /usr=/akshatha/test/ --relocate /var=/akshatha/test/ (rpm_package)

etc has directories : aaa bbb ccc

usr has directories : ddd eee fff

var has directories : hhh iii jjj

so i see inside /akshatha/test/

$cd /akshatha/test/

$ ls -ltr

aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff hhh iii jjj  (and some_other_contents_which is not of rpm package)

the relocation is sucessful..very happy for that.

But when i do uninstall of that rpm :

rpm -e (rpm_package_name)

i see the contents inside the directories aaa bbb ccc ... are deleted.

but the directories does not get deleted as part of uninstall.

if i delete these folders forcefully during uninstall :

rpm takes  RPM_PREFIX_INSTALL=/akshatha/test

which actually deletes the entire test folder(which also has someother contents which are not of that rpm package)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the %files section you define what belongs to an rpm and what will be removed when the rpm will be removed.

If you put:

```
%files
/etc/test/*
```

The all files inside `/etc/test` will belong to the rpm but not the `test` directory. If you put

```
%files
/etc/test
```

Then the `/etc/test` directory with all it's content will belong to the rpm and will also be removed upon uninstallation.

Comment: but i wont know what is the relocation path..it can be known only during installation time .. i cannot hardcode /etc/test.. user can relocate /etc to any other location they want..RPM does not identify $RPM_PREFIX_INSTALL while packaging.. it only does during pre and post

Comment: @AkshathaRamesh you do have a `%files` section? I suppose that in your `%files` section you now have something like `/etc/file`. I am saying that if you want `/akshatha/test` to be removed after installing with relocation; you have to specify in your rpm that the `etc` directory; mapped to `/akshatha/test/` belongs to your rpm. So you need to add `/etc` or `%dir /etc` to your `%files` section.

Comment: yes, it did work.. i was trying with /etc/file.. and hence it used to remove only file.. now i tried with /etc.. which inturn deleted entire etc ..thank you so much